# MySQL mylty sorting a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **MySQL table** users:

```
#  | name     | parent|
________________________
1  | USER 1   | 
2  | USER 2   |
3  | user 12  | 1
4  | user 22  | 2
5  | user 11  | 1
6  | USER 3   |
7  | user 21  | 2
8  | user 31  | 6
```

Here the **parent** record is the primary key of the same table. What i need is to sort the table both parent-wise and name-wise.

This is the result that I need to get:

```
#  | name     | parent|
________________________
1  | USER 1   | 
5  | user 11  | 1
3  | user 12  | 1
2  | USER 2   |
7  | user 21  | 2
4  | user 22  | 2
6  | USER 3   |
8  | user 31  | 6
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name ASC, parent ASC`

Comment: i tried that, and it will sort parent first and then child... i need to get each child along with parent as a hierarchy within same table

Comment: I noticed the PHP tag there, is a PHP-based answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one level of parents you can do:

```
select u.*
from users u
order by coalesce(parent, #), #;
```

(This assumes that the id of the parent is smaller than the id of the children, as is the case with the sample data in the question.)

If you have multiple levels of parents (grandparents and so on), then a single MySQL query is problematic.  MySQL doesn't directly support hierarchical or recursive queries.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know your use case, I think what you are doing is a symptom of poor design.
If possible, a rethink might be in order.

Nevertheless, I think this works

`` SELECT * FROM users
ORDER BY 
    CASE `parent`
        WHEN NOT NULL THEN `parent`
        ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(`users`.`name`, ' ', -1) END
    ASC ``

Simple explanation:
Sorts by parent field if not null. 
Otherwise use the number found in the name field (extracted by separating by the space).

Assumes number will always be separated by a space, and as with Gordon's answer, only works with a single parent.